# Abstract Algebra subgroup and coset proof help

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Show that for any $a \in G$, $aH = H$ if and only if $a \in H$.

Proof:
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with some $a \in G$.
Suppose $aH = H$. Then $e \in H$ since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $e \in G$.
So $ae \in aH$ by definition of a left coset.
Thus $ae = h$, so $a \in aH = H$. Hence, $a \in H$.

(my professor wrote that this next part is unclear and I am not sure how to fix it)

Suppose $a \in H$. Let some element $k \in aH$.
Then there exists $k = ax$ for some $x \in H$. So $a \in H$ and $x \in H$.
Then $ax \in H$ by closure. Thus, $k \in H$ and $aH \subseteq H$.
Now, let some element $j$ be in $H$. So if $a \in H$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $a^{-1} \in H$.
Then $h = (a^{-1})j \in H$ since $a^{-1} \in H$ and $j \in H$.
So $ah = a(a^{-1})j = ej = j$. Thus $j \in aH$.
Therefore, $H \subseteq aH$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your professor's proof is a bit too clunky personally.  The converse is obvious since $H$ is a subgroup and thus closed under multiplication.  Here's a much shorter proof for the forward, using contrapositive:

Let $h, h' \in H$.  Let $g \in G$ \ $H$.

Suppose $gh = h'$.  Do a bit of rearranging, we get $g = h'h^{-1} \Rightarrow g \in H$.  This is because $h$ and $h'$ are elements of $H$, and $H$ is closed under multiplication.  Note that we assumed $g$ was not an element of H, so we have arrived at a contradiction!  Thus, $gH  \neq H$.

---

**Edit**: An even easier method.  Suppose $g \not\in H$.  Then $gH \neq H$ since $e \in H$ and $g \cdot e = g$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof $a \in H \implies aH = H$ is done by proving two things: $a \in H \implies aH \subseteq H$ and $a \in H \implies aH \supseteq H$. In general, for two sets $A$ and $B$, if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \supseteq B$, then $A = B$.

The first is done like this. Let $k \in aH$. By definition of left coset, you can write $k = ah$ for some $h \in H$. But because $a \in H$ as well, $k = ah$ is in $H$, by closure under multiplication. So $aH \subseteq H$.

The second: Let $h \in H$. Since $a \in H$, and $H$ is a subgroup, $a^{-1} \in H$. By closure $a^{-1} h \in H$. But by definition of left coset, $aH$ must contain $a(a^{-1} h) = (aa^{-1})h = h$. So $H \subseteq aH$.

Answer (score 0):

In the second part you are showing $aH=H$. The way to do this is to show that $aH \subset H$ and $H \subset aH$.

So the strategy is to show if $a \in H$ then $aH \subset H$ and $H \subset aH$. Read the proof again keeping this in mind. I can write the proof of the individual steps, but it will be similar to what you have written already anyway!